# Place Holder Text Excel - Multiple Defaults

Tags: excel, vba

A kind gentleman helped me on here before with generating some VBA code to create place holder text in excel. Now I'm not versed in such code and am not to sure how to achieve the result I am looking for. I was wondering if I could receive a little assistance.

With his code here, I was able to achieve the effect I was looking for, however I now need to place another place holder in place for a different column with different default text.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'the formula reference
Dim defaultFormula As String
defaultFormula = "=$C$1"

'The default text cell:
Dim defaultText As Range
Set defaultText = Range("C1")

'The cells you want to monitor:
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C7:C999,D7:D999,G7:G999") '## Modify as needed

'Cell iterator
Dim cl As Range

If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Avoid infinite looping
Application.EnableEvents = False

'If the user has deleted the value in the cell, then replace it with the     formula:
For Each cl In Intersect(Target, rng)
If Trim(cl.Value) = vbNullString Then
    cl.Formula = defaultFormula
End If
Next

'Turn on Events:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I tried to create the same result with an alternate cell using this code here but I don't think this is the correct way. If someone could nudge me in the right direction I would be eternally grateful.

Here's what I came up with;

```
'the formula reference
Dim defaultFormula1 As String
defaultFormula1 = "=$D$1"

'The default text cell:
Dim defaultText1 As Range
Set defaultText1 = Range("D1")

'The cells you want to monitor:
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("E7:E999") '## Modify as needed

'Cell iterator
Dim dl As Range

If Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Avoid infinite looping
Application.EnableEvents = False

'If the user has deleted the value in the cell, then replace it with the     formula:
For Each dl In Intersect(Target, rng1)
If Trim(dl.Value) = vbNullString Then
    dl.Formula = defaultFormula1
End If
Next

'Turn on Events:
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: What are you  trying to do? You just want the Default stuff to go in the "D" column, everything else the same?

Comment: If I was to explain it in the simplest way I can it would be. C1 has text and replicates the text into C7:C999 if those fields are empty. I need to replicate the same result but use D1 for the reference cell and replicate it to E7:E999. Essentially creating another different placeholder, while leaving the other intact.

Comment: Ah, okay - one more clarification, why is it a `Worksheet_Change` event? If the user changes *any* cell in range `E7:E999`, you want this to run, correct?

Comment: I believe that is correct yes.

Comment: Why don't you think your second macro is incorrect? I tried it and it worked for me. If I put "Automobile" in `D1` and delete the text in any cell in the range `E7:E999`, it correctly fills that cell with "Automobile".  If I type "Car" over the cell that has "Automobile", then "Car" stays there. (Note: You're filling in the blanks with a formula, so if you change `D1, then the text down there will change too).  What's the macro **not** doing that you expect it to? How is it "messing up"?

Comment: I have my code beneath the original. so I think the two are arguing. I get the result with The first, but not the second.

Comment: Your code has to be between `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` and the `End Sub` final line for the second part of your script to fire when you make changes on the sheet. Is that how you have it? Also you declare the same variables again, this in my mind should throw an error in VBA.

Comment: I have both code sections between the private sub and end sub. If I split the two between two private subs I get an ambiguous code error from VBA.

Comment: Oh wait, are you trying to combine these?? Are these supposed to be two separate Worksheet_Change events (i.e. running on two separate sheets), or combined - you want Range `E7:E999` to default to the "D" column values, and the range `C7:C999,D7:D999,G7:G999` to default to C values??

Comment: Yes I think this is what I am trying to achieve as I think they are arguing. They are both on the same worksheet.

Comment: Hopefully final clarification: Will the range `E7:E999` look to `E1` for the default value, or will `E7:E999` look a column to the left, to `D1` for the value?  Can you perhaps post a screenshot of sample data and where you expect the data to be?

Comment: That is correct as I am hiding these default cells from the user. So I want to tell cells E7:E999 to look at D1 for their value if empty. If a screen shot helps I'll put one up. :)

Comment: Hope this helps, (http://i.stack.imgur.com/8irbf.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' I am assuming that the Ranges you want to fill with Default Values are ONE column to the RIGHT of the Default Text
' i.e. Range `D7:D999` will look for the default value in `C1`

'the formula reference
Dim defaultFormula As String
defaultFormula = "=r1c" & Target.Column - 1

'The default text cell:
Dim defaultText As Range
Set defaultText = Range("C1")

'The cells you want to monitor:
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C7:C999,D7:D999,E7:E999,G7:G999") '## Modify as needed

'Cell iterator
Dim cl As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then 'If the change happened in any of the `rng` ranges

    'Avoid infinite looping
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'If the user has deleted the value in the cell, then replace it with the     formula:
    For Each cl In Intersect(Target, rng)
    Debug.print cl.value
    If Trim(cl.Value) = vbNullString Then
        cl.Formula = defaultFormula
    End If
    Next

End If
'Turn on Events:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Since your Default Values are in row 1 of the column LEFT of your "changing ranges", all you basically needed to do was switch your `defaultFormula` to look there.  I used R1C1 style notation.  This way, it looks at your `Target.Colum`, being the column you changed a cell in, then looks LEFT one column (`- 1`) and up to row 1 (`R1` means "row 1").

I also changed the `If Intersect() Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` just for personal preference, but you can of course leave yours.

Comment: Almost there, I'm having issues with C7:C999 and G7:G999 displaying correctly. C7:C999 is displaying '0' and G7:G999 is displaying '00/01/00'.

Comment: C is looking at > =$B$1 for its value and G is looking at > =$F$1. I need them to look at C1 also.

Comment: Scratch that, I just figured if the top row is hidden I can define these fields with the same text.

Comment: Your answer is spot on, thank you for your assistance, kind sir! :)

Comment: @Null - Happy to help!